# Get a random object from a list of objects with template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm listing every fonts I have in my models database under each icon from another model.

I would like to get **one** random font for each icon.

Here is how I show my template file :

```
{% for Fo in FormOne %}
    {% for Ft in FormTwo %}
        {% for f in Ft.icon.all %}          
            <p>{{ f.icon_name }}</p>        #for each icon name
            {% for f in Fo.checkbox.all %}
                <p>{{ f.font_name }}</p>    #show one random font name.
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I got the context of my view like this :

```
context = {'FormOne':FormOne.objects.all(), 'FormTwo':FormTwo.objects.all()}
```

here is my **model** structure :

```
class Font(models.Model):
    font_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    font_css = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class FormOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    checkbox = models.ManyToManyField(Font, blank=True)
    ...

class Icons(models.Model):
    icon_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class FormTwo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(FormOne)
    icon = models.ManyToManyField(Icons, blank=True)
    ...
```

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: use the `random` built-in filter. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#random)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [custom filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Here is a filter to pick a random element from a list :

```
import random
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter('random_font', random_font)
def random_font(l):       
    f = dict(random.choice(list(l)))
    return "%s : %s" % (f['font_name'], f['font_css'])
```

n.b., there is a lot of work in writing your first custom filter which includes creating a `register` instance, registering your custom filters 
using the `register.filter` decorator and `load`ing your library of custom
filters in your template.

Comment: Tried it but I couldn't use it, because it list me the first character of each font name, but it doesn't return me only one font name

Comment: `{% for f|pick_random in Fo.checkbox.all %}` I have to insert the tag in this line, how do I do ? (this code shows me nothing)

Comment: try : `{{Fo.checkbox.all|pick_random}}`

Comment: this causes a little problem, `{{ Fo.checkbox.all|random }}` shows me the font_name only but I'd like to show the `font_name` + `font_css`

Comment: I've edited the filter function to suit your needs, also renamed it to `random_font`